# Add New Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I manipulate my source array using javascript in order to get the following:

```
 [ {Metric: totalRevenue, 2019-12-28: 91722000000, 2019-09-30: 63936000000}, {Metric: costOfRevenue, 2019-12-28: 56773000000, 2019-09-30: 39771000000}, ...etc.  ]
```

Where Each financial statement item is considered a new **metric** that has a new key value that combines  **fiscalDate** value and the value for that **Line Item**.

Example JSON here:

```
iex = [
  {
    reportDate: "2019-12-31",
    fiscalDate: "2019-12-28",
    currency: "USD",
    totalRevenue: 91722000000,
    costOfRevenue: 56773000000,
    grossProfit: 34949000000,
    researchAndDevelopment: 4451000000,
    sellingGeneralAndAdmin: 5197000000,
    operatingExpense: 66421000000,
    operatingIncome: 25301000000,
    otherIncomeExpenseNet: 617000000,
    ebit: 25301000000,
    interestIncome: 785000000,
    pretaxIncome: 25918000000,
    incomeTax: 3682000000,
    minorityInterest: 0,
    netIncome: 22236000000,
    netIncomeBasic: 22236000000,
  },
    {
    "reportDate": "2019-09-30",
    "fiscalDate": "2019-09-28",
     "currency": "USD",
     "totalRevenue": 63936000000,
     "costOfRevenue": 39771000000,
      "grossProfit": 24165000000,
      "researchAndDevelopment": 4110000000,
      "sellingGeneralAndAdmin": 4578000000,
      "operatingExpense": 48459000000,
     "operatingIncome": 15477000000,
    "otherIncomeExpenseNet": 650000000,
    "ebit": 15477000000,
    "interestIncome": 810000000,
    "pretaxIncome": 16127000000,
    "incomeTax": 2441000000,
    "minorityInterest": 0,
    "netIncome": 13686000000,
    "netIncomeBasic": 13686000000
    } 
];
```

Image of Data Source: [IEX data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugL6X.png)

Code I've tried below:

```
function generateChartData(iex) {
  var chartData = [],
    categories = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < iex.length; i++) {
    var totalRevenue = iex[i].totalRevenue;
    var fiscalDate = iex[i].fiscalDate;
    // add new data point
    if (categories[fiscalDate] === undefined) {
      categories[fiscalDate] = {
        Metric: totalRevenue,
      };
      chartData.push(categories[fiscalDate]);
    }
    // add value to existing data point
    categories[fiscalDate][fiscalDate] = totalRevenue;
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

Comment: what u have tried ?? add ur version of code. Add minimal working code

Comment: I've tried the above code..Trying to loop through each element in the array and pushing it into a new array..Honestly not entirely sure how to create a new key value pair and then manipulate it into a new array

Comment: you mean u want to group by date ?? total revenue

Comment: I need it for every Metric like Cost of Revenue

Comment: your expected result deosnt seems correct

Comment: @xdeepakv how so?

Comment: check my answer, if i understand correct.. later refactor.

Comment: @xdeepakv Your answer is super close...I just need it combined..I replied below to your answer. Thanks

Comment: @xdeepakv Thanks man..You're incredible

Comment: Please check now.. i have simplified a lot. If match ur answer please accept as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted the method, now can be done one loop.

```js
function generateChartData(iex) {
  return iex.reduce(
    (m, item) => {
      const fiscalDate = item["fiscalDate"];
      if (!m[0][fiscalDate]) m[0][fiscalDate] = 0;
      if (!m[1][fiscalDate]) m[1][fiscalDate] = 0;
      if (!m[2][fiscalDate]) m[2][fiscalDate] = 0;
      m[0][fiscalDate] += item.totalRevenue;
      m[1][fiscalDate] += item.costOfRevenue;
      m[2][fiscalDate] += item.grossProfit;
      return m;
    },
    [
      { Metric: "totalRevenue" },
      { Metric: "costOfRevenue" },
      { Metric: "grossProfit" },
    ]
  );
}
const iex = [{"reportDate":"2019-12-31","fiscalDate":"2019-12-28","currency":"USD","totalRevenue":91722000000,"costOfRevenue":56773000000,"grossProfit":34949000000,"researchAndDevelopment":4451000000,"sellingGeneralAndAdmin":5197000000,"operatingExpense":66421000000,"operatingIncome":25301000000,"otherIncomeExpenseNet":617000000,"ebit":25301000000,"interestIncome":785000000,"pretaxIncome":25918000000,"incomeTax":3682000000,"minorityInterest":0,"netIncome":22236000000,"netIncomeBasic":22236000000},{"reportDate":"2019-09-30","fiscalDate":"2019-09-28","currency":"USD","totalRevenue":63936000000,"costOfRevenue":39771000000,"grossProfit":24165000000,"researchAndDevelopment":4110000000,"sellingGeneralAndAdmin":4578000000,"operatingExpense":48459000000,"operatingIncome":15477000000,"otherIncomeExpenseNet":650000000,"ebit":15477000000,"interestIncome":810000000,"pretaxIncome":16127000000,"incomeTax":2441000000,"minorityInterest":0,"netIncome":13686000000,"netIncomeBasic":13686000000}]

console.log(
  generateChartData(iex)
);
```

**Another way:**

```js
function generateChartData(keys, iex) {
  const [k1, k2, k3] = keys;
  const def = keys.map((k) => ({ Metric: k }));
  return iex.reduce((m, item) => {
    const fiscalDate = item.fiscalDate;
    if (!m[0][fiscalDate]) m[0][fiscalDate] = 0;
    if (!m[1][fiscalDate]) m[1][fiscalDate] = 0;
    if (!m[2][fiscalDate]) m[2][fiscalDate] = 0;
    m[0][fiscalDate] += item[k1];
    m[1][fiscalDate] += item[k2];
    m[2][fiscalDate] += item[k3];
    return m;
  }, def);
}
const iex = [{"reportDate":"2019-12-31","fiscalDate":"2019-12-28","currency":"USD","totalRevenue":91722000000,"costOfRevenue":56773000000,"grossProfit":34949000000,"researchAndDevelopment":4451000000,"sellingGeneralAndAdmin":5197000000,"operatingExpense":66421000000,"operatingIncome":25301000000,"otherIncomeExpenseNet":617000000,"ebit":25301000000,"interestIncome":785000000,"pretaxIncome":25918000000,"incomeTax":3682000000,"minorityInterest":0,"netIncome":22236000000,"netIncomeBasic":22236000000},{"reportDate":"2019-09-30","fiscalDate":"2019-09-28","currency":"USD","totalRevenue":63936000000,"costOfRevenue":39771000000,"grossProfit":24165000000,"researchAndDevelopment":4110000000,"sellingGeneralAndAdmin":4578000000,"operatingExpense":48459000000,"operatingIncome":15477000000,"otherIncomeExpenseNet":650000000,"ebit":15477000000,"interestIncome":810000000,"pretaxIncome":16127000000,"incomeTax":2441000000,"minorityInterest":0,"netIncome":13686000000,"netIncomeBasic":13686000000}]
console.log(
  generateChartData(["totalRevenue", "costOfRevenue", "grossProfit"], iex)
);
```

Comment: This is very close...I need it to look like this:

[
  [
    {
      "Metric": "totalRevenue",
      "2019-12-28": 91722000000,
          "2019-09-28": 63936000000
    },
      "Metric": "costOfRevenue",
      "2019-12-28": 56773000000,
       "2019-09-28": 39771000000
    }

Comment: Please check now!